# Has China expressed the desire to claim Outer Manchuria recently?

Tags: russian-federation, china

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iibs7buNwxQ

Has China expressed the desire to claim Outer Manchuria recently?

> Outstanding boundary issues between China and Russia were officially
> settled in the 1991 Sino–Soviet Border Agreement. Article 6 of the
> 2001 Sino–Russian Treaty of Friendship provides that the contracting
> parties—the People's Republic of China and the Russian Federation—have
> no territorial claims.
>
> As the Republic of China, now based in Taiwan, has never recognized
> the People's Republic of China nor its border treaties with other
> countries, some maps published in Taiwan still show the entire
> Heixiazi Island and the Sixty-Four Villages East of the River as
> Chinese territories. However, these maps show Outer Manchuria,
> sometimes called "lost territories in the Northeast" (東北失地), to be
> Russian territory.
>
> Some Manchu and Han Chinese regard Outer Manchuria as territory that
> was unfairly taken away, as in Mao's comments leading up to the
> Sino–Soviet border conflict.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Manchuria

I am wondering if during a speech or in a document drafted by the document China ever expressed the desire to get this territory back, especially after Article 6 of the 2001 Sino–Russian Treaty of Friendship, because the video seems to imply that this territory is something China really wants when I don't see any sign that it's even in the government's mind or plan.

Comment: BTW, that video makes the even more improbable claim that the US knew nothing of the Ukrainian plans for a [counter]offensive around Kharkiv.

Comment: which is in fact plain false https://www.politico.com/news/2022/09/12/ukraines-rapid-gains-in-northern-counteroffensive-00056244 although if one is very charitable the bombastic presenter "misspoke" and wanted to say sometihng about how surprised Western officials declared themsevles of the result.

Comment: *If [China] ever expressed the desire to get this territory back* Here do you mean specifically ROC or both ROC and PRC?

Comment: @SJuan76: I'd *assume* the PRC, since they have de facto control over the overwhelming majority of "China's" land area and population.  But, as mentioned, [the ROC claims only a small part of Outer Manchuria.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan#/media/File:ROC_Administrative_and_Claims.svg)

Comment: Falun Gong publications have clearly expressed a demand to take back the region. Following FG suppression, the existing agreement is held up as a reason to oppose the government that made the agreement. The intention seems to be to appeal to the common opinions of Chinese non FG members.

Answer (score 12):

The video is clearly speculating that China *might* do that at some point if Russia is really weakened and becomes very dependent on China. It doesn't say that China gave any recent signs. Treaties can be denounced. And people can speculate a lot on youtube, especially in clickbait videos, which many of these "analyses" are.

Besides, as I [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Sino-Russian_Treaty_of_Friendship), the treaty that you mentioned automatically expires and has to be renewed.

> On June 28, 2021, Russia and China extended the treaty for another 5 years after its expiration in February 2022.

But of course, the nuclear of arsenal of Russia is still going to be there... although the nuclear armed India and Pakistan still have not settled their territorial disputes, so it's still possible for such countries to lay claim on their neighbors' territory. Whether that gets them anywhere is another matter.

Comment: And nuclear armed China and India have neither.

Comment: Russia is not exactly a reliable nation to uphold treaties, so whatever they signed is just for show. China and Russia do NOT get along. Just look at their borders.